# How can I put a decorative img underneath a text?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

```
  <div class="event-main-container"> 
    <div class="firstContent">
      <img src="IMG ASSETS/Ellipse 6.png">
      <h3>Events</h3>
      <p>
        If we're gonna walk though the <br> woods, we need a little path. We'll <br> paint
        one happy little tree right here. <br />
        There's not a thing in the world wrong <br> with washing your brush. Don't
        fiddle <br> with it all day.
      </p>
   
    </div>
```

[how do I make it so my ellipse is positioned like the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyGzW.png)

Comment: Position the wrapper relative, and then the image absolute ...

Comment: Is there a reason for not having the ellipse as a background image?

Answer (score 0):

As @Cbroe mentioned, You can set `position:relative` to the parent, and `position:absolute` to your ellipse, and then set `top`, `left`, `bottom` or `right`.

Also, you can make an ellipse in css to avoid loading an image

```css
body{
  background-color:#f8e68b;
}
.firstContent{
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left:100px;
  
  position:relative;
}
h3{
  text-align:center;
  color:#45597e;
}
.firstContent:before{
  content:"";
  background-color: #ecd03e;
  height: 150px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;

  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
  left:-20px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstContent">
  <h3>Events</h3>
  <p>
    If we're gonna walk though the <br> woods, we need a little path. We'll <br> paint
    one happy little tree right here. <br />
    There's not a thing in the world wrong <br> with washing your brush. Don't
    fiddle <br> with it all day.
  </p>
</div>
```

Note that instead of adding `br` in your text, you could set the `width` or `max-width` of your paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Set position:relative on .firstContent then use position:absolute on your ellipse. Use the left and top rules to position the element where you want it to go. I've replaced the image with a div as I don't have your source but you get the general idea.

```css
.firstContent {
  position: relative;
  isolation: isolate;
  background-color: #f9e78b;
  width: 30ch;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
}
h3 {
  margin-left: 5ch;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #4e538a;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 16px;
  top: 56px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background-color: #ecd03e;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-main-container"> 
    <div class="firstContent">
      <div class='circle'></div>
      <h3>Events</h3>
      <p>
        If we're gonna walk though the <br> woods, we need a little path. We'll <br> paint
        one happy little tree right here. <br />
        There's not a thing in the world wrong <br> with washing your brush. Don't
        fiddle <br> with it all day.
      </p>
   
    </div>
```